# create uitextfield over uiwebview textfield programmatically in iphone

Tags: iphone, cordova, webview, uitextfield

I want to create uiTextField overlay on uiWebview and it is on the same position on the uiwebview input field.

i.e.: when user clicks on the textfield available on webview then new UITextfield is created and displayed over html textfield. when Editing is done uitextfield disappears then value is placed inside the textfield inside webview.

My application is in Phonegap architecture. please provide any suggestion or examples.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

take one view, set background to clearColor & put textField inside it, show dynamically when you clicks your webView TextField. because of clearColor it feels like it is on webView